# Can name servers be pointed to different sub (and sub sub) domains?

Tags: domain-name-system, subdomain, nameserver

here's the issue.

There is a sub domain, let's call it flag.domain.com using names servers, let's say ns1.dns.com and ns2.dns.com. There is also a sub sub domain events.flag.domain.com which also currently points to the same name servers.

The issue here is that the site that sits on flag.domain.com needs to be moved to another server. It would be easy to ask the current hosting company to simply change an a name record to point to the new server, but in the longer term this may be more hassle.

My question is.. is it possible to use different name servers to point to flag.domain.com (i.e. new name servers) and continue to use existing name servers for events.flag.domain.com ?

Does this make any sense? Thanks in advance for any help.
J

Comment: Why not just change the A record of flag.domain.com?

Comment: Hi Nathan, good Q. Well the current hosts are being phased out so the thought is that it would be easier if possible to control the sub domain by changing name servers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, what you are looking for is called [Zone Delegation](http://www.zytrax.com/books/dns/ch9/delegate.html), and it does exactly what you are asking, says that another server is responsible for a zone, or a sub zone.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. That looks exactly what we are looking for. So each zone hypothetically could use different name servers if needed?

Comment: Certainly, it's not exactly efficient, or easy to administer, but it is entirely possible.